# Is it ok to use Redux to handle UI state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm starting to develop an app using React Native (I'm quite new to the React and React Native world) and I'll use Redux for state management.

But I have a doubt: should I use Redux for the UI state?

So far I had 2 chances to decide to use Redux or local state in UI components.

I have a modal in the main screen (state is a boolean).

Then I have a FAQ screen with an accordion, and I have the questions and answers in an array where each question also has an "expanded" (boolean).

I know there's a lot of discussion about this, but I can't choose because I keep reading "If you use React for the rest of the state you might as well use it for your UI state" but then I read "You don't need to stick to Redux for everything, you still can, and should use local state".

Thoughts?

Comment: Try to search for answer, the best and the simplest one by Dan Abramov can be found here: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1287#issuecomment-175351978

Answer (score 1):

Well...

I recommend to use Redux only for global state and React state for handle UI state or local class states only.

I used this pattern in all of my projects and works very well, separate the scopes can be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to implement component state to handle UI changes. Your redux store will be responsible for non-UI state related to business Logic like : info about logged users, request results etc. UI component state will handle changes like : open/close dropdown flag or button color change etc